# Can't get jstree working - "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'delegate'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm trying to get the jstree plugin working, following the "Predefined HTML" example on this page: `http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/1_datasources.html`

To avoid any conflict with anything else that might be happening, i've tried to get it working in the simplest possible page, in my public dropbox folder: `http://dl.dropbox.com/u/846812/jstree_example/jstree_example.html`

The only js i've included in my page is jquery and the main jstree file, `jsTree/jquery.jstree.js`. (The documentation is a bit shaky about what exactly i need to include, but maybe this is the problem).  The rest of the files i downloaded are next to `jquery.jstree.js`, in the `jsTree` folder.

I've also got my predefined html, a nested list in a div with id="folder_tree".

When the javascript runs, i get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'delegate'`, from line 3629 of the `jquery.jstree.js` file - hopefully you'll see this error too.

Can anyone have a look at the page (the dropbox link above) and see what i'm doing wrong?  thanks, max

(note that the file links in that page don't work - they don't need to in order for jstree to work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is since version 1.4.2

You are using a older version of jQuery

Comment: Thanks Manuel.  I'm using 1.3.2 here, which is the version referenced in the example on the jstree demo page.  Are you saying that i need to upgrade jquery to 1.4.2 or later?

Comment: the delegate method is introduced since verson 1.4.2 so i think you do need this version instead of the 1.3.2 version you're using now

Comment: ah - got it.  I used jquery 1.4.2, and changed the tree setup to be .jstree() rather than .tree().  I think that the demo i refer to above is for an older version of jstree, and i was using the actual files from a more recent version.  thanks!